# sas convert string date to date and compare them

Tags: string, function, date, sas

I have a date store like a string in the format 
  anomesdia_mail='2014-01-31'

I would need to convert it to a date in order to compare it with another date:
  sevendays_after='13FEB14:00:00:00'.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
anomesdia_mail1 = input(substr(strip(anomesdia_mail),1,10),MMDDYY10.);
```

and after this I would need to compare both:

```
sum(case when b.anomesdia_mail<=a.sevendays_after then 1 else 0 end)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the yymmdd10. format for `anomesdia_mail` - the string is in that format, not the mmddyy10. format that you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try treating `sevendays_after` as a datetime variable and use datepart to extract the date from it before you compare it with your date variable, e.g.

```
data _null_;
    a = "2014-01-31";
    b = "13FEB14:00:00:00";
    a2 = input(a,yymmdd10.);
    b2 = datepart(input(b,datetime.));
    c= (a2 = b2);
    put _all_;
run;
```

Comment: it works in your file, but not in mine...my variable was 'sevendays_after = intnx('DTDAY',creation_date,7);'
format sevendays_after DATEtime17.;
so I tried: 
'sevendays_after1 = datepart(input(sevendays_after,datetime.));' but the result is null.... maybe because the format is datetime17.

Comment: In that case you've created sevendays_after as a date, not a datetime, and this advice doesn't apply.

Comment: Also note that applying a datetime format to a date value (i.e. days since 01JAN1960) will not display the expected value as datetimes are the number of seconds since 01JAN1960:00:00:00. A format does not change the underlying value, simply how it's displayed.

Answer (score 0):

to convert it in a date I have to use the input function.
for example= mail date was a string in the format DD-MM-YYYY
so first: 
I have to give it the proper order:

```
mesdiaano_mail_string = catx(separator,substr(mail_date,6,2),substr(mail_date,9,2),substr(mail_date,1,4));
```

then convert it in date format:

```
mail_date_int = input(substr(strip(mesdiaano_mail_string),1,10),MMDDYY10.);
```

with datepart function I can convert it to an integer with the numbers of days since 1960 and perform operation: